# Understanding problems switchIfEmpty and switchIfEmpty

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I try to write web app using kotlin/webflux/r2dbc:postgresql
But I have proplem. I can't understand why switchIfEmpty call if result of work hackerService.resetPassword not empty

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/reset/password/{link}", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
    fun resetPassword(@PathVariable link: String, req: ResetPassword): Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> {
        return userservice.resetPassword(link, req)
                .map { ResponseEntity.ok("OK") }
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()))
    }
```

Service

```
fun resetPassword(link: String, resetPassword: ResetPassword): Mono<Void> {
        BLEException.checkArgument(resetPassword.newPassword == resetPassword.checkPassword, PASSWORD_NOT_MATCH)
        return resetPasswordRepository.findByLink(link)
                .flatMap { updateAccount(it.userId, password = resetPassword.newPassword) }
                .flatMap { resetPasswordRepository.deleteByUserId(it.id!!) }
    }
```

Method updateAccount is setting new password and resetPasswordRepository.deleteByUserId drop row from table.
And this method work, and I expecte not empty Mono as result of resetPassword

But finaly I have as result 404 error.

I would be glad for any help, thanks

Comment: if you return `Mono<Void>`, stream is considered as "empty" - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.monoThen; you can return "updated rows" instead - is using `DatabaseClient` - .fetch().rowsUpdated()

Comment: I think you need to show the implementations of both `updateAccount` and `resetPasswordRepository` so we can understand whether or not they would return Mono<Void> type

Comment: Just wondering since you are using Kotlin any reason you don’t want to use coroutine based API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `resetPasswordRepository` is a spring data `ReactiveCrudRepository`, then the return type of all `delete*()` methods is `Mono<Void>`

`Mono<Void>` is the type of an empty Mono.

As a result, `switchIsEmpty` will always be invoked as the object returned from `resetPassword` is an empty Mono.

Answer (score 0):

two ways I can think of how to solve it as a follow up to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64343260/14024602)

1. return a Mono.error instead of empty in the service and map the error to a ResponseStatusException in the controller

```
return resetPasswordRepository.findByLink(link)
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(UserNotFound()))
```

2. use the .then*() operation to map the result of delete* from `Mono<Void>` to something else, say the deleted entity. You'd need to change the result type of the service method, of course

```
    .flatMap { resetPasswordRepository.deleteByUserId(it.id!!).thenReturn(it) }
```